# jquery - How to select specific table row

Tags: jquery, tablerow

I have a problem. I can create dynamically multiple rows. Each row has 2 `<td>`. Each `<td>` has class, `tdDebit` and `tdCredit`.

```
<table id="tblAcctForm">
 <tr>
  <td class="tdDebit"><input type="text" /></td>
  <td class="tdCredit"><input type="text" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to happen is that when I type to an input inside a `<td>` with class either `tdDebit` or `tdCredit` the other input on the same row will be disabled. What happens is that when I type something on the input inside a `<td>` with class `tdDebit` or `tdCredit` all the input is disabled. I only want the input on the same row which I typed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("tr .tdDebit input").live("keyup", function()  {
    checkContent(this, "tr .tdCredit input");
  });

  $("tr .tdCredit input").live("keyup", function()  {
    checkContent(this, "tr .tdDebit input");
  });
});

function checkContent (activeElem, otherElem) {
  if ($.trim($(activeElem).val()) != "")
    $(otherElem).attr("disabled", "disabled");
   else
    $(otherElem).removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Please see my working code here : http://jsfiddle.net/pcmwg/

PS: Create multiple rows before testing it.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're passing into to `otherElem` parameter is too general: it selects all inputs within all .tdDebit/.tdCredit's within all tr's on the page.

Instead, pass it the direct value relative to the input element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("tr .tdDebit input").live("keyup", function()  {
    var toDisable = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tdCredit input');
    checkContent(this, toDisable);
  });

  $("tr .tdCredit input").live("keyup", function()  {
    var toDisable = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tdDebit input');
    checkContent(this, toDisable);
  });
});
```

Better yet, make it more generic:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr input").live("keyup", function()  {
    var toDisable = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').not(this);
    checkContent(this, toDisable);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jdfM/1/

Comment: also, if you're using jQuery 1.7 or greater, us `on` instead of `live` : http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

```
checkContent(this, $(this).siblings(".tdCredit input"));
checkContent(this, $(this).siblings(".tdDebit input"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it..second argument is no longer needed

```
function checkContent (activeElem, otherElem) {
    var $input=$(activeElem), $otherInput=$input.parent().next().find('input');
        if ($.trim($input.val()) != "")
            $otherInput.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        else
           $otherInput.removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/pcmwg/1/